# Create a Simple Login page using MVC Design Pattern in Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am developing an Android application. I have to create a simple Login page using MVC Design Pattern. I never use this MVC Design Pattern. Can anybody give me some examples or any idea about this..?? I have seen some examples but didn't get solution. Please give me some idea...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC design pattern, which means Model View Controller, is an approach which divides the code into 3 distinct responsibilities:

Model - This is the data you are handling. You might have some entities (for example a Customer, a Shopping Cart, Transactions, Products)

View - This is how things are being rendered or displayed to the user. It involves the UI and also the presentation logic (what should be displayed when). Often templating systems are used or something similar.

Controller - This is what binds the two together. When a button is pressed on the View, the controller takes care of interpreting the event to do something to the Model (i.e. retrieve more data, or change it, etc.), after which the view can be triggered to re-render a new screen with the new data following the action of the user.

The above is just a rough description of what MVC is. You can find more details [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html).

Android already follows this pattern in a sense. You have the XML file of an activity which represents the login form, so the View, while the actual class of the activity itself would be the Controller. The Model is your own data. Some controls, such as ListView etc. require that you wrap this data in some adapter but the concept is still the same.

Comment: Good answer. To expand on this answer, the "model" in the OP's qusetion is the code that actually performs the login validation and raises an event/callback back to the activity to indicate success or failure. And while the model supports operations for the view, it knows nothing about the view and could presumably work without one. Use interfaces between classes wherever possible for maximum re-usability.

Comment: Yep agreed. I would say the Controller is what does the validation though based on the user's inputs and action, the model is just the account of the user (or the username/hashed password entry to be more specific) and maybe the session information stored somewhere that says that the user is logged in. As you said though, the view is using information from the model to determine what to display, and using interfaces maximises re-usability and also potential enhancements (for example authentication using different mechanisms).